# Why does my batch file generated text not format properly?

Tags: file, batch-file

The Problem:

I'm trying to create a batch file which randomly generates passwords, but I cannot seem to get the generated passwords to format properly.

Before, I just chose to generate numbers, but I realized that it wasn't very secure for users, and I needed to include letters and numbers. I attempted, but it output the wrong thing (kind of).

I want the generated passwords to be at least `8` characters long, and `32` characters maximum. I tried it, but it completely broke the code and it wouldn't output anything at all. Also, it outputs the same passwords for each one on every option. For example, if I chose option `1` (generate `2` passwords), it would output `ud8aqas` and `ud8aqas`. If I chose option `2` (generate `5` passwords), it would output `p9dkda`, `p9dkda`, `p9dkda`, `p9dkda`, and `p9dkda`, and so on.

The code that I want to use:

```
@echo off
:Start2
cls
goto Start
:Start
title DotPass Password Generator [BETA]
echo Thanks for using DotPass! If you have any questions, feel free to email us at mhartmix@gmail.com.
echo Please maximise this program so you can see all of the details we have shown!
echo ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo DotPass will generate you a new PIN (or password, if that's what you're going to use it for).
echo You can use these for any of your online accounts! Remember to always note the PIN/password down somewhere!
echo -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo Note: The passwords/PIN's can only be seen by you, not us. To read more, go to github.com/TechGeekMic/DotPass/blob/Main/security.md
echo Passwords generated are never stored on the cloud, or locally, so that's why you should make a note of your randomly generated PIN/password.
echo -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo How many passwords do you want DotPass to generate?
echo 1) 2 Generated Random Password
echo 2) 5 Generated Random Passwords
echo 3) 10 Generated Random Passwords
echo Type the number of your choice below. ( i.e 2 )
set input=
set /p input= Choice:
if %input%==1 goto A if NOT goto Start2
if %input%==2 goto B if NOT goto Start2
if %input%==3 goto C if NOT goto Start2
:A
cls
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set _RNDLength=12
Set _Alphanumeric=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
Set _Str=%_Alphanumeric%987654321
:_LenLoop
IF NOT "%_Str:~18%"=="" SET _Str=%_Str:~9%& SET /A _Len+=9& GOTO :_LenLoop
SET _tmp=%_Str:~9,1%
SET /A _Len=_Len+_tmp
Set _count=0
SET _RndAlphaNum=
:_loop
Set /a _count+=1
SET _RND=%Random%
Set /A _RND=_RND%%%_Len%
SET _RndAlphaNum=!_RndAlphaNum!!_Alphanumeric:~%_RND%,1!
If !_count! lss %_RNDLength% goto _loop
echo Your two randomly generated passwords are !_RndAlphaNum! and !_RndAlphaNum!
)
echo What do you want do to? Here are a few options.
echo 1) Go back to the beginning
echo 2) Exit DotPass
echo 3) Shutdown your computer
echo Type the number of your choice below. ( i.e 1 )
set input=
set /p input= Choice:
if %input%==1 goto Start2 if NOT goto Start 2
if %input%==2 goto Exit if NOT goto Start 2
if %input%==3 goto Shutdown if NOT goto Start 2
:Shutdown
shutdown
:Exit
exit
:B
cls
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set _RNDLength=12
Set _Alphanumeric=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
Set _Str=%_Alphanumeric%987654321
:_LenLoop
IF NOT "%_Str:~18%"=="" SET _Str=%_Str:~9%& SET /A _Len+=9& GOTO :_LenLoop
SET _tmp=%_Str:~9,1%
SET /A _Len=_Len+_tmp
Set _count=0
SET _RndAlphaNum=
:_loop
Set /a _count+=1
SET _RND=%Random%
Set /A _RND=_RND%%%_Len%
SET _RndAlphaNum=!_RndAlphaNum!!_Alphanumeric:~%_RND%,1!
If !_count! lss %_RNDLength% goto _loop
echo Your five randomly generated passwords for you are !_RndAlphaNum!, !_RndAlphaNum!, !_RndAlphaNum!, !_RndAlphaNum! and !_RndAlphaNum!
)
echo What do you want do to? Here are a few options.
echo 1) Go back to the beginning and start again
echo 2) Exit DotPass
echo Type the number of your choice below. ( i.e 1 )
set input=
set /p input= Choice:
if %input%==1 goto Start2 if NOT goto Start 2
if %input%==2 goto Exit if NOT goto Start 2
if %input%==3 goto Shutdown if NOT goto Start 2
:C
cls
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set _RNDLength=12
Set _Alphanumeric=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
Set _Str=%_Alphanumeric%987654321
:_LenLoop
IF NOT "%_Str:~18%"=="" SET _Str=%_Str:~9%& SET /A _Len+=9& GOTO :_LenLoop
SET _tmp=%_Str:~9,1%
SET /A _Len=_Len+_tmp
Set _count=0
SET _RndAlphaNum=
:_loop
Set /a _count+=1
SET _RND=%Random%
Set /A _RND=_RND%%%_Len%
SET _RndAlphaNum=!_RndAlphaNum!!_Alphanumeric:~%_RND%,1!
If !_count! lss %_RNDLength% goto _loop
echo Your ten randomly generated passwords for you are !_RndAlphaNum!, !_RndAlphaNum!, !_RndAlphaNum!, !_RndAlphaNum!, !_RndAlphaNum!, !_RndAlphaNum!, !_RndAlphaNum!, !_RndAlphaNum!, !_RndAlphaNum! and !_RndAlphaNum!
echo What do you want do to? Here are a few options.
echo 1) Start again
echo 2) Exit DotPass
set input=
set /p input= Choice:
if %input%==1 goto Start2 if NOT goto Start 2
if %input%==2 goto Exit if NOT goto Start 2
if %input%==3 goto Shutdown if NOT goto Start 2
```

You can try it out for yourself as long as you don't publish it or modify it.

I am very new to batch scripts! Can someone help?

Comment: I'd suggest, to begin with, you should look at changing your instances of, `SET _RND=%Random%`, and `Set /A _RND=_RND%%%_Len%`, to `SET "_RND=!RANDOM!"`, and `Set /A _RND = _RND %% _Len`. Id also advise you that there's currently nothing to stop your end users from entering poison characters at the input prompts, and you've not added any code to cater for those scenarios.

Comment: _You can try it out for yourself as long as you don't publish it or modify it._ - see [What is the license for the content I post?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing)

Comment: It's unlikely we'd want to publish a script, which doesn't work. And conversely, in order for it to work, it would need to be modified! Also based upon the statement "I am very new to batch scripts!", and the fact that other than the `echo` stuff, I've seen everything in that script before, I'm going to suggest that it couldn't really be termed as yours to stipulate such a condition, as it's really plagiarized from other sources.

Comment: BTW, there are other issues with your code too, I was just wondering whether you intended to take the credit for me mentioning them to you? whether you were going to reference anyone who helps? or even provide a link to this site/post in the content? I may not want to reveal those issues, if I'm not satisfied with your answer!

Comment: Please read [mcve]

Comment: uhm - why do you expect `echo !var! !var! !var! !var!` to output four different values?

Comment: I think it's fair to say you failed to search relevant Q&A's prior to `1)` Asking your question, and `2)` Writing a script where your knowledge base is not yet sufficient for the task. Had you done a simple seach, you would be using a function such as those at [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34160029/simple-function-to-generate-random-alphanumeric-string-with-definable-length)