# The script does not show symbols even with correct typing

Tags: batch-file

I'm creating a script that *basically* creates **passwords** and things like that **randomly**, done in batch.

**My problem is that** certain symbols he is not interpreting, even though *I have all the care in the world with quotation marks*, and I would like that to work. I haven't tried anything yet, I just tried to copy the variables in the common CMD and see if they gave an error but no, as I have no idea what my mistake is here, but, from time to time, my program returns "The command syntax is invalid", and never shows the symbols reserved by the system, such as `!@#%&*(`, as far as I could notice.

The code below shows the *first moment* where they are interpreted, together with a variable that brings me a random value from 0 to 20.

```
if "%rand%" equ "1" set "symbol=!"
if "%rand%" equ "2" set "symbol=@"
if "%rand%" equ "3" set "symbol=#"
if "%rand%" equ "4" set "symbol=$"
if "%rand%" equ "5" set "symbol=%"
if "%rand%" equ "6" set "symbol=¨"
if "%rand%" equ "7" set "symbol=&"
if "%rand%" equ "8" set "symbol=*"
if "%rand%" equ "9" set "symbol=("
...
```

Soon after, the code that displays the answer on the screen, along with the treatment of it.

```
    :postchoice
     if "%letter%" neq "" set "pwd=%pwd%%letter%"
     if "%symbol%" neq "" set "pwd=%pwd%%symbol%"
     if "%letter%" equ "" (
        if "%symbol%" equ "" set "pwd=%pwd%%rand:~-1%")
    
    if "%lenght%" leq "0" set /p "output=%pwd%"<nul&echo.&exit /b
    goto repassword
```

`%lenght%` refers to the length of the password, reaching the end of the loop when the length reaches 0. The `repassword` label makes the loop again until lenght reaches 0.
The program, until then, works without problems. I even used the `set /p` trick to avoid conflicts with `echo`.
I'm using the powershell and VBS tags because I'm accepting responses that use this, but nothing else. PowerShell, VBScript and Batch are the only answers I can accept.

I really tried to see if there is ANY of these symbols. Making a loop with the password being created 50000 times in a file and then searching for it. Nothing. The `@` appears only 5 times in 50000. The program is generating everything perfectly, but it does not generate these symbols at all. `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` has been active since the beginning of the program.

In fact, I can say that yes, the program arrives in these symbols, because the same is done with the letters and all the letters can be displayed, without exception. In a way that is the same, percentage. Not a problem with `%rand%`.

Example to reproduce the error:

```
@echo off
set rand=5
if "%rand%" equ "1" set "symbol=!"
if "%rand%" equ "2" set "symbol=@"
if "%rand%" equ "3" set "symbol=#"
if "%rand%" equ "4" set "symbol=$"
if "%rand%" equ "5" set "symbol=%"
if "%rand%" equ "6" set "symbol=¨"
if "%rand%" equ "7" set "symbol=&"
if "%rand%" equ "8" set "symbol=*"
if "%rand%" equ "9" set "symbol=("
set /p "output=%symbol%"<nul
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of your code, i.e. sufficient code that we can copy and run to repeat the issue you are experiencing. Currently what you've provided is too minimal, we need to be able to create those variables, like you have, and just as importantly be able to output whatever you are, in order to see that issue manifest itself.

Comment: @Compo You can clearly see, understand and reproduce the example. Even without it, you can see the error. The error was in the single `%`. The only thing that are NOT in the code is the `%letter%`, that i do NOT want help with, and the `%rand%`, wich i clearly specified that goes from 0 to 20 randomly. I believe I have provided enough.

Comment: @Compo I already answered my question, but thanks for the help.

Comment: @Compo In fact, you seem experienced, can you tell me if there is any way to edit the title? "Program" is not very appropriate, "Script" is.

Comment: @Compo I just read how to [ask a good question][1] and they say this about reproducible code:
 "But don't just copy in your entire program! Not only is this likely to get you in trouble if you're posting your employer's code, it likely includes a lot of irrelevant details that readers will need to ignore when trying to reproduce the problem."

  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Compo if you just add `@echo off`,`set rand=(some number 0 to 20)` and then the `set /p "output=%symbol%` you can reproduce the error. Literally 3 lines, and one of them is just for aesthetics.

Comment: @Compo With that said, it is clear that it is possible to reproduce the code, and more than that, as the system I use to create random numbers and the like is unnecessary. Would I have to copy the 620 lines of code for you to reproduce? I'm sorry, but it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @KatornHypno that is why the tutorial is called MINIMAL REPRODUCEABLE EXAMPLE. You should always provide all the code required to reproduce the given problem.  Nobody told you to post the entire script or company secrets.  I always obfuscate file paths and sensitive information when I post questions like that. It should not be that hard of a concept to understand.

Comment: @Squashman I just don't see the need to add 3 obvious lines of code to a script like this, and not even the need for Compo to say that the entire question would be completely erased because of 3 lines of code, as he said in the answer I informed my question itself. Anyway, I added the example to the question.

Comment: Okey, I'll play your game @KatornHypno, since you've decided to post nine comments all specifically in response to mine! Your question appears to be far simpler than all of that bloat in your question, and subsequent self-answer. It appears to be "In a batch file, how do I define a variable containing a literal percent character, and, _(I'm assuming this part)_, subsequently output it as intended?" Example `Set "var=%"`, then `Echo %var%`. Is that the crux of it? And are you absolutely sure that this question has never been asked and answered before, on StackOverflow.?

Comment: @Compo Thanks. Yes, nine comments, to ensure that no doubts would be left behind. I'm surprised you stopped to count the quantity. Yes, it is an extremely simple question but it has been haunting me since yesterday, because I had no idea where the error was, so much so that this is what I specify above. In my view, it had to do with the quotes or the setlocal, and yes, that was more or less the doubt. I'm not sure if it has been answered before because the site has many pages, but I've been researching since yesterday, and since I didn't know what the problem was, I didn't know how to ask too.

Comment: @Compo People like me may end up having the same problem, as symbols in batch scripts are a bit complicated, and the question + answer already complements, in my view, all the questions related to that. Because to display a symbol, you just need to enclose it in quotes, repeat it or change the form of display, as I did with `set /p`. I just forgot that batch worked like this, because I don't program in just one language, but I needed to program in that one specifically.

Comment: @Compo Despite everything, I thank you. When I asked myself about the only change that should be made to create a "minimally reproducible example" I looked at the variable `%rand%` and I found a way to test exactly which ones were failing, and I wondered which one was mine. Incidentally, the problem, for me, was very complex, since I didn't even know what the error was if the quotes were in place, since batch is not such an accurate language, such as, for example, C, and that’s why I couldn’t specify. Do you think I should now, that I know the mistake, for future readers?

Comment: Random string generation can be either simplified or empowered with the use of for loops and substring modification. [See here for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66550416/12343998). With regards to your above comments, Batch syntax may well be alien for someone who comes to it from other languages, however it does have a fairly symple syntax once you get to know it.

Comment: @T3RR0R I would love to know how to perform this process in a simple way in a FOR loop without the use of `setlocal`. But, how does that help, exactly? Besides, of course, reducing the script size and aesthetics? Can you show me a example?
Yes, that IS alien, but it is not something unexpected, since it was not made to be a programming language, but only tools to help with the user or computer technician! Thanks for the tip anyway @T3RR0R, apreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just understood the problem. To make it easier, I set the `%rand%` to be automatically 5, wich is `%`. Apparently, even during the quotation marks, some symbols like `%` and `!` are considered, even if they have no value in the `%`. So all I needed to do was add one more of that symbol to be considered text or add `^` behind it and it would have my code working. Batch is weird.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, it is a solution to an issue you have not explained. Unless you improve your question, such that others can offer solutions, it should be deleted, because it isn't useful to future readers, who will be unable to determine if they have the same problem.

Comment: If you understand batch-file, you may find that future readers can YES understand the answer and the question. It is nothing more than: I have a code written with perfect quotes, but some of the symbols here are not being shown. Does anyone know what it is and how to solve it? And then the answer: The `%` and some others may need a `^` or a double symbol to be registered.

Comment: @Compo Wich i explained in the answer.

Comment: @Compo I can even show to you: "Apparently, even during the quotation marks, these are considered, even if they have no value in the %. So all I needed to do was add one more of that symbol to be considered text or add ^ behind it and it would have my code working.". If something is spelled wrong, I can fix it for a better understanding, but the question and answer are not wrong in logical questions.

Comment: @CompoI already edited it for a better understanding.